# How to make Sinatra work over HTTPS/SSL?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, sinatra

As the title says, Google doesn't give anything useful concerning this.

How do I set up and configure HTTPS/SSL for Sinatra apps?

How do I create a HTTPS route?

I have never used HTTPS for my apps before and have no experience tweaking Rack/whatever, so I appreciate detailed answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess you need to setup your Web-server, not Sinatra, to work with SSL. In Sinatra you can use the `request.secure?` method to check for the SSL usage.

SSL + Nginx: [the first article](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpSslModule), [the second one](http://rubypond.com/blog/setting-up-nginx-ssl-and-virtual-hosts).

Answer (score 23):

this seems to do it for me:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

CERT_PATH = '/opt/myCA/server/'

webrick_options = {
        :Port               => 8443,
        :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
        :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
        :SSLEnable          => true,
        :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
        :SSLCertificate     => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(  File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.crt")).read),
        :SSLPrivateKey      => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(          File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.key")).read),
        :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ]
}

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
    post '/' do
      "Hellow, world!"
    end            
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run MyServer, webrick_options
```

[hat tip to http://www.networkworld.com/columnists/2007/090507-dr-internet.html]

Comment: want to give some tips on [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462558/error-bad-uri-when-trying-to-get-webrick-to-accept-https)?

Comment: Works as intended but how do you set the bind address? :BindAddress doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: This seems like a more appropriate answer to the question

Answer (score 16):

I think using [rack-ssl](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl) is the best option.

Then you just do:

```
class Application < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::SSL

  get '/' do
    'SSL FTW!'
  end
end
```

and all `http://` calls are redirected to `https://`

Comment: This only works if you have an SSL certificate installed

Comment: Well, you always should, I'm not talking about "VERIFY_NONE" option here :)

Answer (score 11):

I modified code of [richard_bw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631493/richard-bw) as to be able close or restart it with Ctrl+C:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
    post '/' do
      "Hello, world!\n"
    end            
end

CERT_PATH = '/opt/myCA/server/'

webrick_options = {
  :Port               => 8443,
  :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
  :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
  :SSLEnable          => true,
  :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
  :SSLCertificate     => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(  File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "server.crt")).read),
  :SSLPrivateKey      => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(          File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "server.key")).read),
  :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ],
  :app                => MyServer
}
Rack::Server.start webrick_options
```

Comment: How do I generate a certificate for Webrick?

Comment: Depens on reasons why you need it. If it's just testing you may issue self-signed one. This is way to do it on ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49196/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: If you need it for production, I would check your domain registrar for such service. Ussualy you have to pay for it.

Comment: which one should I use: /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem or
/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key?

Comment: I used the `:Host` Rack option to be able to listen to the public interface otherwise it was always only localhost : `:Host => "0.0.0.0"`. Cfr. [Class: Rack::Server](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Server#initialize-instance_method). `:BindAddress` Webrick option did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding multiple servers, the webrick specific answers here are fine, but webrick specific.

When using Puma, the configuration can be simplified:

```rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
    post '/' do
      "Hello, world!\n"
    end
end

Rack::Server.start app: MyServer, Host: "ssl://0.0.0.0:8443?key=privkey.pem&cert=cert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could find after a broad search, is the solution posted by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571814/frank) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432921/enabling-ssl-for-a-thin-server-and-sinatra).

Simply place the following at the top of your Sinatra classic app to force your application to use HTTPS:

```
require 'rack/ssl-enforcer'
use Rack::SslEnforcer
```