# Securing my Server API on the Cloud(Sinatra/Ruby)

Tags: ruby, cordova, sinatra, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am developing an App for iphone,android using PhoneGap for the client side. On the server side, i have a Restful API with Sinatra/Ruby(Not Rails). The App is free and anyone can access the services but i need to make sure the minimal level of security is implemented so my API is available 24/7.

I heard about oAuth but i am not sure if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

oAuth is a standard for authorization across different authorization domains (e.g. between services) and is probably not what you want.

The easiest way to secure a REST API is the usage of HTTPS. To secure Sinatra have a look at [How to make Sinatra work over HTTPS/SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696558/how-to-make-sinatra-work-over-https-ssl)