# "Error bad URI" when trying to get WEBrick to accept HTTPS

Tags: ruby, https, sinatra, rack, webrick

So I've got a simple Sinatra site:

```
# app.rb         
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do       
  'Hello world!' 
end
```

And I can set up rack to serve it over HTTP:

```
# config.ru              
require './app'          
run Sinatra::Application 

# vim: ft=ruby
```

And it works fine when I browse to `http://localhost:9292`:

```
% rackup
[2013-01-22 10:27:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-01-22 10:27:52] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-darwin10.7.4]
[2013-01-22 10:27:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7525 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2013 10:28:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0177            
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2013 10:28:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 447 0.0007
```

I've [generated a self-signed certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html), and after some googling, thought I found [a way of setting up my rack file to use the cert and serve HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373973/9859):

```
# config.ru                                                                     
require './app'                                                                 
require 'webrick'                                                               

Rack::Server.start(                                                             
  :Port             => 9292,                                                    
  :Logger           => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),         
  :app              => Sinatra::Application,                                    
  :SSLEnable        => true,                                                    
  :SSLVerifyClient  => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,                               
  :SSLPrivateKey    => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new( File.read "server.key" ),        
  :SSLCertificate   => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( File.read "server.crt" ),
  :SSLCertName      => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]                  
)                                                                               

# vim: ft=ruby
```

But when I visit `https://localhost:9292` I get `Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` and webrick is ... unhappy:

```
% rackup
[2013-01-22 10:46:28] DEBUG TCPServer.new(0.0.0.0, 9292)
[2013-01-22 10:46:28] DEBUG TCPServer.new(::, 9292)
[2013-01-22 10:46:28] DEBUG Rack::Handler::WEBrick is mounted on /.
[2013-01-22 10:46:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7660 port=9292
[2013-01-22 10:46:33] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:62185
[2013-01-22 10:46:33] ERROR bad URI `?w~Rx03I?\x06?\x00\x00H\x00??'.
localhost - - [22/Jan/2013:10:46:33 EST] "\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x01P??Y?KOƛ\x0Ew/yO;P\x1E\x13 ?w~Rx03I?\x06?\x00\x00H\x00??" 400 316
- -> ?w~Rx03I?\x06?\x00\x00H\x00??
[2013-01-22 10:46:33] DEBUG close: 127.0.0.1:62185
```

Feel free to try it yourself, all the files you need to run it (config.ru, app.rb, server.crt, server.key) are in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4595883).

So I'm obviously doing something wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: I tried this before too, I gave up. I'll be interested to see if you can find a way to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
require "webrick/https"
```

to make it working

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I just added that to `config.ru`, and now webrick spits `!! Invalid request` and the browser still says `Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`.