# Changing port that WEBrick starts on via Rack::Cascade & Grape

Tags: ruby, rack, webrick, ruby-grape

I have a grape application and I'd like to modify the port WEBrick starts on, can anybody point me in the right direction...

```
require './api/api.rb'

use Rack::Session::Cookie
run Rack::Cascade.new [API]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [run method takes a Port parameter](http://rubylearning.com/blog/a-quick-introduction-to-rack/). All you must do is pass it the port, so:

```
run Rack::Cascade.new [API], :Port => 58080
```

Hope that helps... If you've further problems, do leave a comment.

Comment: This didn't seem to work, any ideas? 

[2014-08-24 22:00:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9774 port=9292

Comment: wont work, as Cascade doesn't accept parameters like this https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/cascade.rb

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to explicitly run it on Webrick, one solution might be:

```
webrick_options = {
  :Port               => 9393,
  :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
}

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run(API, webrick_options)
```

However if you need Cascade (multiple apps) I didn't figure that one out yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696558/how-to-make-sinatra-work-over-https-ssl