# How to make WEBrick work only over HTTPS/TLS1.2 to avoid POODLE?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, webrick, tls1.2

I was looking at the code here: [How to make Sinatra work over HTTPS/SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696558/how-to-make-sinatra-work-over-https-ssl)

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

CERT_PATH = '/opt/myCA/server/'

webrick_options = {
        :Port               => 8443,
        :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
        :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
        :SSLEnable          => true,
        :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
        :SSLCertificate     => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(  File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.crt")).read),
        :SSLPrivateKey      => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(          File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "my-server.key")).read),
        :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ]
}

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
    post '/' do
      "Hellow, world!"
    end            
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run MyServer, webrick_options
```

How does one disable SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLS1.0, and only allow TLS1.2? This will remediate the POODLE vulnerability in older protocols. This is the first time I am experimenting with ruby/WEBrick so pretty novice here. Thanks for any help!